# Dio interceptor for refreshing access token

Tags: flutter, dio

I am trying to implement a access token refresh with a Dio interceptor. I have looked at examples I could find, none of which seem to work.

Here is my attempt:

```
class AuthInterceptor extends QueuedInterceptor {
  final Dio dio;
  final AuthService authService;

  AuthInterceptor(this.dio, this.authService);

  @override
  void onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    var accessToken = await TokenRepository.getAccessToken();

    if (accessToken != null) {
      logDebug('Access-Token: $accessToken');
      options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';
    }
    return handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    if (err.type == DioErrorType.response && err.response?.statusCode == 401) {
      var accessToken = await TokenRepository.getAccessToken();

      if (accessToken != null) {
        final refreshToken = await TokenRepository.getRefreshToken();
        final refreshResult = await authService
            .refresh(RefreshRequest(accessToken, refreshToken!));
        await TokenRepository.setAccessToken(refreshResult.accessToken);
        handler.resolve(await _retry(err.requestOptions));
      } else {
        di<NavigationHelper>().navigateClearHistory(LoginPage());
        handler.reject(err);
      }
    } else {
      handler.next(err);
    }
  }

  Future&lt;Response&lt;dynamic&gt;&gt; _retry(RequestOptions requestOptions) async {
    final options = Options(
      method: requestOptions.method,
      headers: requestOptions.headers,
    );
    return dio.request&lt;dynamic&gt;(requestOptions.path,
        data: requestOptions.data,
        queryParameters: requestOptions.queryParameters,
        options: options);
  }
}
```

It kind of works, I do get a new access token. But there is something wrong with how I end the onError override. I do not think the handler gets properly finished? I think the handler.resolve is wrong, but how should I this be implemented? How can I finish this handler properly and perform the retry call with the new access token?

Comment: When you say the handler is not properly finished, I assume you are facing issues?

Comment: Please descript the part "something wrong" in detail and why you think it is wrong.

Comment: handler.resolve() means the error is resolved and stops the other errror interceptors.

Answer (score 20):

Although there is not much information about how to get a new token in case of expiration using the Dio interceptor, I will try my best to help you.

### What is a HttpClient Interceptor?

HttpClient interceptors aim to modify, track and verify HTTP requests and responses from and to the server.

As you can see from the scheme, the interceptor is part of the client, and is the most edge feature in our application.

[image]

### Token management using Interceptors

Since interceptors are the last part of sending HTTP requests to the servers, It's a good place to handle request retries, and get new tokens in case of expiration.

### Problem with your attempt

Let's talk a bit about your code, and try to break each part of it.

**onRequest:**

Although this part should work just fine, It's inefficient using `await` to get the access token on each HTTP request. It will drastically slow your app and the duration you retrieve your HTTP response.

I recommend you create a `loadAccessToken()` function that will be responsible loading your token to a cached repository, and use that cached token on every request.

Note, that I don't know what your `TokenRepository.getAccessToken()` function does behind the scene. But in case it's an HTTP request, be aware that it will be intercepted too! And if you have problem to reach your server, you will get into infinite loop of trying to get your token.

As I will explain later, I'm using the [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) package to save new tokens securely within the app, while loading that token, to cache, on the first HTTP request.

**onError:**

I recommend you to use the [jwt_decode](https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decoder) package, to identify expired tokens **before** sending them to the server (onRequest). That way, you will retrieve new tokens only in case of expiration, and each HTTP request will be sent with verified tokens only.

Thanks to @FDuhen comment, it's still good to mention that it's important to identify and handle 401 responses (since not all 401 are related to token expiration). You can do that via your interceptor for global behavior (like redirecting your users back to the Login flow), or per request (and handle it from your `ApiRepository`). For the simplicity of the example, I won't override the `onError` Interceptor function.

### My approach

Now let's take a look at my code. It's not perfect, but hopefully, it will help you to understand better how to handle tokens using interceptors.

First, I have created a `loadAccessToken()` function as part of my `tokenRepository` class, which aims to arm the token into the cache config repository.

That function works with three steps:

1. Checks if the token is in cache config.
2. If not, then get try to get the token from local storage (using [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)).
3. If it does not exist locally, then try to get that token from the server.

On each step (1, 2) I verify that the token is not expired using the [jwt_decoder](https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decoder) package. If it's expired, then I get it from the server.

Each time you are getting a new token from the server, you need to save it locally using the [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) (we don't want to save it using shared_preferences since it's not secure). That way, your token will be saved securely, and retrieving it will be fast.

**My `loadAccessToken` function:**

```
/// Tries to get accessToken from [AppConfig], localSecureStorage or Keycloak
  /// servers, and update them if necessary
  Future<String?> get loadAccessToken async {
    // get token from cache
    var accessToken = _config.accessToken;
    if (accessToken != null && !tokenHasExpired(accessToken)) {
      return accessToken;
    }
    // get token from secure storage
    accessToken =
        await LocalSecureStorageRepository.get(SecureStorageKeys.accessToken);
    if (accessToken != null && !tokenHasExpired(accessToken)) {
      // update cache
      _config.accessToken = accessToken;
      return accessToken;
    }
    // get token from Keycloak server
    final keycloakTokenResponse = await _accessTokenFromKeycloakServer;
    accessToken = keycloakTokenResponse.accessToken;
    final refreshToken = keycloakTokenResponse.refreshToken;
    if (!tokenHasExpired(accessToken) && !tokenHasExpired(refreshToken)) {
      // update secure storage
      await Future.wait([
        LocalSecureStorageRepository.update(
          SecureStorageKeys.accessToken,
          accessToken,
        ),
        LocalSecureStorageRepository.update(
          SecureStorageKeys.refreshToken,
          refreshToken,
        )
      ]);
      // update cache
      _config.accessToken = accessToken;
      return accessToken;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And here is the `tokenHasExpired` function (using the [jwt_decoder](https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decoder) package):

```
bool tokenHasExpired(String? token) {
    if (token == null) return true;
    return Jwt.isExpired(token);
  }
```

Now, it will be much easier to handle access tokens using our interceptor. As you can see below (in my interceptor example), I'm passing a singleton `AppConfig` instance and a `tokenRepository` that contains the `loadAccessToken()` function we talked about earlier.

All I'm doing on my override `onRequest` function, is to

1. Verify that the request should be used with an access token (not that relevant to our discussion).
2. Get the token from the cache config (using the `AppConfig` instance).
3. In case it does not exist on the cache (probably first HTTP request within app open), or the cached token has expired, then in both situations load a new access token using the `loadAccessToken` function (first from storage, only then from server token provider).

**My interceptor:**

```
class ApiProviderTokenInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  ApiProviderTokenInterceptor(this._config, this._tokenRepository);

  final AppConfig _config;
  final TokenRepository _tokenRepository;

  @override
  Future<void> onRequest(
    RequestOptions options,
    RequestInterceptorHandler handler,
  ) async {
    if (options.headers['requires-token'] == 'false') {
      // if the request doesn't need token, then just continue to the next
      // interceptor
      options.headers.remove('requiresToken'); //remove the auxiliary header
      return handler.next(options);
    }

    var token = _config.accessToken;
    if (token == null || _tokenRepository.tokenHasExpired(token)) {
      token = await _tokenRepository.loadAccessToken;
    }

    options.headers.addAll({'authorization': 'Bearer ${token!}'});
    return handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(
    Response<dynamic> response,
    ResponseInterceptorHandler handler,
  ) {
    return handler.next(response);
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) {
    // <-- here you can handle 401 response, which is not related to token expiration, globally to all requests
    return handler.next(err);
  }
}
```

In case you are getting an error on retrieving a new token from the server (on the `loadAccessToken()` function). Then handle the error on the `tokenRepository` and decide what to present to your client (something general like "There is a problem with our servers, please try again later", should be fine).

### Bonus

You can add the built-in Dio `LogInterceptor` to print every request and response (really helpful for debugging).

Or you can use the [pretty_dio_logger](https://pub.dev/packages/pretty_dio_logger) package, to print beautiful, colored, request and response logs.

```
_ApiProvider(
        dio
          ..interceptors.add(authInterceptor)
          // ..interceptors.add(LogInterceptor())
          ..interceptors.add(
            PrettyDioLogger(
              requestBody: true,
              requestHeader: true,
            ),
          ),
      );
```

Comment: appreciate the effort

Comment: Relying on the Expiration date of the Token only isn't safe for all of the use-cases. If the Token is invalidated by a third-party (an admin, a website associated to the app...), the Token would still have a valid expiration date, but the request will return a 401 unauthorized. OP's logic is more reliable.

Comment: Hey, @FDuhen thanks for your insight. I have edited my answer based on your comment. See the section about onError :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're almost good to go. The only difference with my current code is that I'm using a new instance of `Dio` to retry the request.

The logic I'm following to implement a Token refresh is :
1- Catch the network error if it's a `401 Unauthorized`.
2- If I do have an `AccessToken`, execute my RefreshToken flow
3a- On success (of the refresh token), proceed the original request in a retry with a **new dio instance**
3b- On error, proceed the original error

Here is the `AuthInterceptor` (don't mind the `apiInterceptor`) I'm using :

```
class AuthInterceptor extends QueuedInterceptorsWrapper {
  AuthInterceptor(this._authentManager, this._apiInterceptor);

  final AuthentManager _authentManager;
  final Interceptor _apiInterceptor;

  @override
  // ignore: avoid_void_async
  void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    //On Unauthorized, the AccessToken or RefreshToken may be outdated
    if (err.response?.statusCode == HttpStatus.unauthorized) {
      debugPrint('AuthInterceptor - Error 401');
      final accessToken = await _authentManager.getAccessTokenFromStorage();

      //Happens on first request if badly handled
      //Or if the user cleaned his local storage at Runtime
      if (accessToken == null || accessToken.isEmpty) {
        debugPrint('AuthInterceptor - No Local AccessToken');
        return handler.next(err);
      }

      try {
        debugPrint('AuthInterceptor - Starting Refresh Flow');
        //Refresh token Flow
        final refreshResult = await _authentManager.refreshToken();
        final token = refreshResult.dataOrThrow as TokenJWT;

        //Getting the retry request
        final response = await _getRetryRequest(err, token);
        debugPrint('AuthInterceptor - Response retrieved, proceeding');

        return handler.resolve(response);
      } on DioError catch (e) {
        debugPrint('AuthInterceptor - Error when retrying with a new Refresh');
        //API Key is Expired OR
        //Refresh token is Expired
        if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
          debugPrint('AuthInterceptor - Error 401 retrying with a new Refresh');
        }
      } on NetworkError catch (e) {
        if (e.type == NetworkErrorType.unauthorized) {
          debugPrint('AuthInterceptor - Error 401 retrying with a new Refresh');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Error during retry - $e');
      }
    }

    handler.next(err);
  }

  Future<Response> _getRetryRequest(DioError err, TokenJWT token) async {
    debugPrint('AuthInterceptor - Building Retry Request');
    //Can crash but we're in a try catch
    final requestOptions = err.response!.requestOptions;
    requestOptions.headers[ApiHeaders.authorization] =
        'Bearer ${token.accessToken}';

    final options = Options(
      method: requestOptions.method,
      headers: requestOptions.headers,
    );

    final dioRefresh = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: requestOptions.baseUrl,
        headers: <String, String>{
          HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        },
      ),
    );

    //Need to inject our custom API Interceptor
    //Because of the temp instance of Dio
    dioRefresh.interceptors.add(_apiInterceptor);

    debugPrint(
      'AuthInterceptor - Triggering Request with '
      '${requestOptions.path}, '
      '${requestOptions.data}, '
      '${requestOptions.queryParameters}, '
      '${options.headers}',
    );

    final response = await dioRefresh.request<dynamic>(
      requestOptions.path,
      data: requestOptions.data,
      queryParameters: requestOptions.queryParameters,
      options: options,
    );

    return response;
  }

  @override
  // ignore: avoid_void_async
  void onRequest(
    RequestOptions options,
    RequestInterceptorHandler handler,
  ) async {
    //Getting cached Access Token, or getting it from storage and caching it
    var accessToken = _authentManager.currentAccessToken;
    accessToken ??= await _authentManager.getAccessTokenFromStorage();

    options.headers.addAll(
      <String, String>{
        ApiHeaders.authorization: 'Bearer $accessToken',
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      },
    );

    handler.next(options);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one example of this, where I am able to refresh the access token using the Dio Interceptor.

```
class DioHelper {
  final Dio dio;
  DioHelper({@required this.dio});

  final CustomSharedPreferences _customSharedPreferences =
      new CustomSharedPreferences();
  static String _baseUrl = BASE_URL;
  String token = "";
  
  void initializeToken(String savedToken) {
    token = savedToken;
    _initApiClient();
  }

  Future<void> initApiClient() {
    dio.interceptors
        .add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) {
      options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
      return options;
    }, onResponse: (Response response) {
      return response;
    }, onError: (DioError error) async {
      RequestOptions origin = error.response.request;
      if (error.response.statusCode == 401) {
        try {
          Response<dynamic> data = await dio.get("your_refresh_url");
          token = data.data['newToken'];
          _customSharedPreferences.setToken(data.data['newToken']);
          origin.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + data.data['newToken'];
          return dio.request(origin.path, options: origin);
        } catch (err) {
          return err;
        }
      }
      return error;
    }));
    dio.options.baseUrl = _baseUrl;
  }

  Future<dynamic> get(String url) async {
    try {
      final response = await dio.get(url);
      var apiResponse = ApiResponse.fromJson(response.data);
      if (apiResponse.status != 200) {
        throw Exception(apiResponse.message);
      }
      return apiResponse.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      // debugging purpose
      print('[Dio Helper - GET] Connection Exception => ' + e.message);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> post(String url,
      {Map headers, @required data, encoding}) async {
    try {
      final response =
          await dio.post(url, data: data, options: Options(headers: headers));
      ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse.fromJson(response.data);
      if (apiResponse.status != 200) {
        throw Exception(apiResponse.message);
      }
      return apiResponse.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      // debugging purpose
      print('[Dio Helper - GET] Connection Exception => ' + e.message);
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

can you look into that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code working in ap in the production, and never had any issues with it.

```
@override
  Future<void> onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
      if (isAccessTokenExpired) {
        try {
          final accessToken = await accessTokenRepo?.refresh();
          options.headers.setOrRemove(
              _authorizationHeader, _authorizationHeaderValue(accessToken));
          saveAccessToken(accessToken);
        } catch (error) {
          saveAccessToken(null);
          handler.reject(DioError(requestOptions: options, error: error));
          return;
        }
      }
    
    return super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401 && _accessToken != null) {
      if (!isAccessTokenExpired) {
        _updateHeader(
            _authorizationHeader, _authorizationHeaderValue(_accessToken));
      }
      // here, I construct and send a new request based on the old one.
      handler.resolve(await _sendRequest(err.requestOptions));
      return;
    }

    try {
      // here, I check the retry count
      if (shouldRetry(err)) {
        await Future.delayed(_retryDelay);

        handler.resolve(await _sendRequest(err.requestOptions));
      } else {
        super.onError(err, handler);
      }
    } catch (_) {
      super.onError(err, handler);
    }
  }
```

All the other code is implementation specific.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple use in my application:

1. create an  `AuthInterceptor.dart`

   ```
   class AuthInterceptor extends QueuedInterceptorsWrapper {

      AuthInterceptor(this._tokenService);

      final TokenService _tokenService;

   @override
   void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {

    if (err.response!.statusCode == 403 || err.response!.statusCode ==401) {

      final options = err.requestOptions;
      final accessToken = await _tokenService.refreshToken();

    if (accessToken == null || accessToken.isEmpty) {

           return handler.reject(err);

     } 
     else {
     options.headers.addAll({'Authorization': accessToken});
     try {
       final _res = await _tokenService.fetch(options);
       return handler.resolve(_res);
     } on DioError catch (e) {
      handler.next(e);
      return;
      }
    }
   }

    @override
    void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler 
    handler) async {
    final String? accessToken = await _tokenService.getToken();
    if (accessToken != null) {
     options.headers.addAll({'Authorization': accessToken});
     }

     log("NEW ACCESS TOKENN $accessToken");

      handler.next(options);
   }

     @override
    void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler{
    handler.next(response);
   }
   ```

   }
2. create `TokenService.dart`

   ```
   Class TokenService extends ApiClient {

   late final DataBaseHandler _dataBaseHandler;

    TokenService(this._dataBaseHandler) {
    _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    receiveTimeout: 60000,
    connectTimeout: 60000,
    responseType: ResponseType.json,
    headers: <String, dynamic>{
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
    ));
   }

   late Dio _dio;

    Future<Response<dynamic>> fetch(RequestOptions options) =>
    _dio.fetch(options);

    Future<String?> refreshToken() async {
    Response response;
    // we use completer to get future value when we get the response
    final tokenSubscription = Completer<String>();  

    final Uri apiUrl = Uri.parse(baseUrl);
    var refresh token = await _dataBaseHandler.read(key: "refreshToken");
    _dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer 
     ${refreshToken?.object}";
    try {
    response = await _dio.postUri(apiUrl);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     //if your refresh token is a model with extra info, decoding it.
     RefreshTokenResponse refreshTokenResponse =
     RefreshTokenResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.toString()));
     databaseHandler.write(key:'accessToken', 
     value:refreshTokenResponse.data.accessToken);

    //let's complete the completer with refresh token here

     tokenSubscription.complete(refreshTokenResponse.data.accessToken);

    } 
   } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
     // don't forget to retun future here: this will updte the future 
     // listener with accessToken
     return tokenSubscription.future; 
   }
      // helper method to get previous accessToken
    Future<String?> getToken() async {
    var accessToken = await _dataBaseHandler.read(key: 
    ApiStrings.accessToken);
    return accessToken?.object.toString();
    }
   ```

   }
3. Finally you can use interceptor on the original Dio client.

   DataBaseHandler is just a local storage service here:

   ```
    class DioClient {
    late Dio _dioClient;

      DioClient() {
      _dioClient = Dio()
      ..interceptors.addAll([
       AuthInterceptor(TokenService(locator<DataBaseHandler>())),
       if (kDebugMode) LogInterceptor(responseBody: true, 
    requestBody: true),
      ])
      ..options.baseUrl = baseUrl
      ..options.headers = headers;
      }
    }
   ```